# Perl System Call not Interpretting Variable Correctly

Tags: perl, system

I'm using Perl to pass a string ($password) to a system line to be interpreted. It doesn't seem to be interpreted correctly though, because when I go to attach the Sparse Bundle it says the authentication failed. As a note, everything after the pipe works fine.

```
$password = chomp($password);

### Create the bash system call to create the sparse bundle with the password
my $cmd = `echo $password | hdiutil create -size 200g -type SPARSEBUNDLE -encryption -stdinpass -volname \"Encrypted Storage for Matt\" -fs \"Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+\" -verbose ~/Desktop/SparseBundle`;
```

**Some sample output:**

```
SLC1087-Matt:backups matt$ ./create_sparsebundle.pl 
DIDiskImageCreatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CSparseBundleDiskImage
DIDiskImageCreatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CSparseDiskImage
DIDiskImageCreatorProbe: interface  3, score    -1000, CRawDiskImage
DIDiskImageCreatorProbe: interface  7, score    -1000, CWOUDIFDiskImage
DIDiskImageCreatorProbe: interface  9, score    -1000, CCFPlugInDiskImage
DIDiskImageCreateWithCFURL: CSparseBundleDiskImage
CBSDBackingStore::createProbe directory, not a valid image file.
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  0, score    -1000, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  1, score     1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  2, score        0, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  5, score     -100, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreateWithCFURL: CBundleBackingStore
DIFileEncodingCreatorProbe: interface  2, score     1000, CEncryptedEncoding
DIFileEncodingCreateWithCFURL: CEncryptedEncoding
DIFileEncodingCreatorProbe: interface  2, score    -1000, CEncryptedEncoding
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  0, score      100, CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  1, score    -1000, CBundleBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  2, score        0, CRAMBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  3, score      100, CCarbonBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreatorProbe: interface  5, score     -100, CCURLBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreateWithCFURL: CBSDBackingStore
DIBackingStoreCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0
DIFileEncodingCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0
DIBackingStoreCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0
DIDiskImageCreateWithCFURL: creator returned 0
DI_kextWaitQuiet: about to call IOServiceWaitQuiet...
DI_kextWaitQuiet: IOServiceWaitQuiet took 0.000003 seconds
2016-05-18 20:59:09.627 diskimages-helper[68122:1796245] *** -[NSMachPort handlePortMessage:]: dropping incoming DO message because the connection is invalid
hdiutil: create: returning 0
SLC1087-Matt:backups matt$ hdiutil attach ~/Desktop/SparseBundle.sparsebundle
Enter password to access "SparseBundle.sparsebundle": 
hdiutil: attach failed - Authentication error
```

Everything seems to work fine but the password is apparently wrong.

Comment: What happens when you just print the password? `system("echo $password")`?

Comment: Have you verified that this will actually works in bash?  - i.e. without perl.  Some apps that I've come across do something funky with passwords and won't pick up stuff using that format.  So open bash and just run `echo TheRealPassword | hdiutil create -size 200g -type SPARSEBUNDLE -encryption -stdinpass -volname \"Encrypted Storage for Matt\" -fs \"Case-sensitive Journaled HFS+\" -verbose ~/Desktop/SparseBundle`

Comment: @GregHNZ, Why? That's not what's he's passing to the shell using Perl.

Comment: @Matt O., The reason it takes the password via STDIN instead of as an argument is that commands are visible to other users on the machine. Use IPC::Run3's `run3` to do it right

Comment: put `print $password;` right after you do `$password = chomp($password);`   Is that what you expected it to be?

Comment: @GregHNZ Yes, it works in Bash. I just tested it again.

Comment: We know about password completly nothing. Maybe this has some special characters interpreted by bash. I suggest swap beginning of line: `echo $password | into `echo \'$password\' |   . This is typical bashs' trap for unwary :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hdiutil` utility requires a null-terminated password.

That is, `"mypass"` isn't good enough. It needs to see `"mypass\0"` because the password is allowed to contain funny characters like embedded newlines.

So, what it's seeing is `"mypass\n"` instead of `"mypass\0"`

You *could* try this as it will work under linux:

```
echo -n -e "mypass\x00" | hdiutil ...
```

But ... AFAICT, the OSX version of echo doesn't have `-e`, so you may need to experiment.

If all else fails, replace the `echo` with:

```
echo "mypass" | perl -e '$_ = <STDIN>; chomp ; print $_,"\x00"'
```

There may be simpler ways to do/express this. You could create a second perl script (call it `passme`):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print $ARGV[0],"\x00";
```

Then replace the `echo` with `passme`. I *would* put double quotes around the argument.

---

**UPDATE:**

> I'm pretty sure because of the stdinpass that the printf has to be piped to the command. I don't know if I'm exactly right on that.

`echo` and `printf` will be piped to the command. But, there are even more ways to do this that I will recommend over those.

As others have mentioned, the cleanest way may be to use `IPC::Run3`. It's one stop shopping.

But, it may not be installed by default on your system [or other OSX systems]. Dunno--YMMV. You may need to investigate this. So, you might have to install it yourself [from CPAN, I presume(?)]

If your script is *only* for your own usage, the above may be fine. However, if you're creating the script to be used by others, it may end up on a system that does not have Run3 and the sysadm won't install it.

So, you have to balance ease of use vs ubiquity. That will be *your* choice.

Run3 sets up *both* `stdin` and `stdout` on the `hdiutil` command, which is what you need because you want to give it the password *and* capture its output.

If you only needed one, you could use perl's `open` function in "pipe" mode. See `man perlipc` for details. It's pretty simple to use. I've got an example for this--see below.

Or, you could "roll your own" equivalent of what `run3` does by using perl's intrinsic `pipe` call. You would need *two* pipes. It's a bit of work, so maybe something for the future.

The biggest problem with the `echo`, `printf`, [and `passme`] approaches is [as others pointed out], is that because they use argv to get the password, they "bleed" it to other processes [briefly].

So, we'd like to have a method that is secure [e.g. Run3 would be]. That's why `hdiutil` takes a password on `stdin` instead of a command line argument.

---

(1) Actually, the simplest way may be to dump the password to a temp file:

```
use Fcntl;

my $fd;
my $tmp = "/tmp/pwfile";

my $password = "whatever";

# NOTE: by using sysopen and setting the 600 permission atomically, we avoid a
# race condition that may allow another user to open this file
unlink($tmp);
sysopen($fd,$tmp,O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,0600) or
    die("unable to open '$tmp' -- $!\n");
syswrite($fd,$password . "\x00");
close($fd)

my $cmd = `hdiutil ... < $tmp`;
unlink($tmp);
```

---

(2) If you don't want to write the password to a temp file, no matter how briefly it may linger around, there is yet another way. It's similar to the `passme` script approach above, *except* it passes down the password as an environment variable. This avoids exposure of the password via command line arguments.

Here's the `passme` variant:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print($ENV{"PASSME"},"\x00");
```

This could also be done with an inline:

```
perl -e 'print($ENV{"PASSME"},"\x00")'
```

Then, your script becomes:

```
my $password = "whatever";

$ENV{"PASSME"} = $password;
my $cmd = `passme | hdiutil ...`;
delete($ENV{"PASSME"});
```

---

(3) Yet another way is the use [the aforementioned] use of perl's `open` in pipe mode. Set it up as an input pipe to `hdiutil` and divert the output to a temp file which you read back after the command has executed.

```
my $fdout;
my $fdin;
my $tmp = "/tmp/results";
my $buf;

my $password = "whatever";

open($fdout,"| hdiutil ... > $tmp") ||
    die("unable to open hdiutil pope -- $!\n");
print($fdout $password,"\x00");
close($fdout);

open($fdin,"<$tmp") ||
    die("unable to open '$tmp' -- $!\n");
while ($buf = <$fdin>) {
    chomp($buf);
    # do whatever ...
}
close($fdin);
```

Comment: It can also be done without the three extraneous processes and without showing the password to everyone on the machine using `use IPC::Run3 qw( run3 ); run3([ 'hdutil', ... ], \"$password\0", \my $stdout);`

Comment: No, what it's seeing is `"1\n"` because he assigned `$password` to be the return value of `chomp`.

Comment: For portability: use `printf` instead of `echo -e`

Comment: I'm pretty sure because of the stdinpass that the printf has to be piped to the command. I don't know if I'm exactly right on that.

Comment: What for that big complication? hdutil can accept end of string by detecting \0 ending character, or by detecting EOF on stdin. We know nothing about password, maybe in it is included some special sequence or character interpreted by bash. Then I suggest to surround password variable by quotes. it is all what is needed.

Comment: @Znik No, `hdiutil` _requires_ an EOS [`\0`] terminated string--check the documentation. Merely getting EOF is _not_ sufficient. I think you should reread my answer [a few times] as what you're suggesting was covered.

Answer (score 6):

Read about what the `chomp` returns. Your code at least rewrites the `$password` variable with an integer presumably `0` or `1`. That caught my eye.

---

The [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments.

Comment: I removed `chomp` and I'm still getting issues. I'll update what I show uptop.